# Sub menu slides up then back down if it is already down selected (bug)

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu, accordion, submenu

Hello I am having a problem with my jQuery vertical accordion style menu.

If you click a sub menu, it drops down. If you click on a different sub menu, the current one slides up and then the one you clicked slides down.

I am using the `.slideUp()` jQuery function to default all sub menus back to the up position before sliding the next one down.

The problem is when you click on a sub menu, it drops down, then you click on the same sub menu, then it slides up and then slides back down again.

How can I prevent this from happening?
Instead I want the submenu to slide up if it is already down.

Please see my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o5w37zva/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in selector. You use below selector slideUp the others submenus and you slides all submenus in the nav.

```
$("#nav ul")
```

If you use this selector, you need the modify it with .not() function and remove the current,$(this) element in your function.

```
$("#nav ul").not($(".submenu-customers")).slideUp();
```

With this selector, if the user click opened submenu, it will be slideUp only. You can see a demo: http://codepen.io/ogzhncrt/pen/bdypBK

Answer (score 1):

I made some fixes of your code:

```js
$('document').ready(function () {
  
    $('#nav li').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        
     $(this).find('> a').addClass('selected-sub');
        $(this).find('.submenu').slideToggle();
        
        $(this).siblings().find('> a').removeClass('selected-sub');
        $(this).siblings().find('.submenu').slideUp();
    });
    
    $('.submenu li').on('click', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

```css
.submenu {
  display: none;
}

ul#nav li, .submenu li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul#nav li a {
  color: #CCC;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 13px 10px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0A0A0A;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

ul#nav li a:hover, ul#submenu li a:hover {
  background-color: #030303;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul#submenu li a {
  color: #CCC;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 13px 10px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0A0A0A;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

ul#nav li a.selected, ul#nav li a:active {
  background-color: #030303;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul#nav li a.selected-sub, ul#nav li a.selected-sub:hover {
  background-color: #3C3C3C;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a id="dashboard" href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li><a id="customers" class="selected-sub" href="#">Customers</a>
        <ul class="submenu submenu-customers">
            <li><a id="view-customers" class="selected" href="#">View Customers</a></li>
            <li><a id="add-customer"  href="#">Add Customer</a></li>
            <li><a id="manage-customers"  href="#">Manage Customers</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a id="invoices" href="#">Invoices</a>
        <ul class="submenu submenu-invoices">
            <li><a id="view-invoices"  href="#">View Invoices</a></li>
            <li><a id="add-invoice"  href="#">Add Invoice</a></li>
            <li><a id="manage-invoices"  href="#">Manage Invoices</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a id="employees" href="#">Employees</a>
        <ul class="submenu submenu-employees">
            <li><a id="view-employees"  href="#">View Employees</a></li>
            <li><a id="add-employee"  href="#">Add Employee</a></li>
            <li><a id="manage-employees"  href="#">Manage Employees</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a id="services" href="#">Services</a>
        <ul class="submenu submenu-services">
            <li><a id="view-services"  href="#">View Services</a></li>
            <li><a id="add-service"  href="#">Add Service</a></li>
            <li><a id="manage-services"  href="#">Manage Services</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a id="clock" href="#">Clock</a></li>
</ul>
```